# Should a domain be accessible via IP as well?

Tags: seo, domains, dns, ip-address, vps

I have a domain which is accessible through the domain name of course.
However, it seats on a unique IP, as it is hosted on a VPS.
But I can't access it through that unique IP (I'm getting into a default page of my webhost). I noticed that some other websites, are accessible through their IP as well (which I find out by whois).

So, is it a good thing that I'm missing? maybe it can be good for SEO? my host says that If they somehow configure the IP to the content of the domain, it could mess some configurations up... not very savvy in that field.

Comment: Yes. It should. There is no need to go blocking perfectly normal and standard behavior. I have run into quite a few situations where I have been unable to reach a website at its domain, but looking up its IP address and visiting that _did_ work. The ability to do this at this saved me from a lot of troubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, generally you wouldn't want the IP address to resolve to your website in addition to the domain itself (providing your domain resolves to the website, this will suffice) - there is often no need for the website to be accessible at the IP address but you could 301 redirect the IP address to your domain in `.htaccess` to handle this if you wish.

Comment: thanks, if there's no benefit to this then i won't change anything i guess.

Answer (score 0):

If the dedicated IP when browsed shows a cPanel page, it means that you do not have a unique/dedicated IP address assigned. The IP is being shared with multiple sites. It should show just your website content.

It is not recommended as it would have duplicate content on the website and the IP address when browsed. Search Engines might penalize you for it.