# Im getting the IP of my VPS instead of the domain in Google search results

Tags: domains, apache, search-results, ip-address

Im getting the ip of my vps instead of the domain in web results. I don't have the same problem with other sites inside the vps.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.todocamino.info
    ServerAlias todocamino.info
    DocumentRoot /home/tirengarfio/workspace/todocamino/web
        DirectoryIndex app.php
    <Directory /home/tirengarfio/workspace/todocamino/web/>
        # Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        #Order allow,deny
        #allow from all
        Require all granted
        FallbackResource /index.php
        # BEGIN EXPIRES
        <IfModule mod_expires.c>
            ExpiresActive On
            ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 days"
            ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
            ExpiresByType text/plain "access plus 1 month"
            ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
            ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
            ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
            ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
            ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
            ExpiresByType application/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
        </IfModule>
        # END EXPIRES
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score -1):

I just answered a similar question here:

[Website opening both on domain name and IP. Is that a problem?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/68776/website-opening-both-on-domain-name-and-ip-is-that-a-problem/)

You may need to redirect any IP address based requests to your domain name.